# Extract user data from a facebook link

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, user-data

I am creating a website that allows users to post a picture to their wall that is linked to an interactive version of that post (the wall post/picture is basically a screen capture of this interactive content) in a unique URL.  I want to be able to gather profile data from any user that clicks the link in Facebook and interacts with the content.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, without user authorization you can´t get ANY data of users who click on a link on Facebook. Check out the Facebook docs for information about authorization/login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2